# Change Sharepoint language with a link?

Tags: 2010, javascript, asp.net, language

[image]

Is there a way to get the language-switch control as static link in the pagelayout? 
I want my users to switch between German and English with a single click.

**Sorry guys, found a solution :D**

```
<script type ="text/javascript"> 
function OnSelectionChange(value)
{ 
var today = new Date();
var oneYear = new Date(today.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var url = window.location.href;
document.cookie = "lcid=" + value + ";path=/;expires=" + oneYear.toGMTString();
window.location.href = url;
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:OnSelectionChange(1031)">German</a>
<a href="javascript:OnSelectionChange(1033)">English</a>
```

Comment: oh you found answer while I was formatting mine :)

Comment: Answer to your question, in order to mark it as an answered question.

Comment: Steve B I need to wait 8 hours before i can -.-'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you examine page source you will see that Select Display Language > Language calls simple javascript:

```
OnSelectionChange(1033);
```

Where 1033 is language id.

I have tried launching this form FireFox FireBug console and it works. So your link could be something like:

```
<a href="" onclick="OnSelectionChange(1033);">English</a>
```

You can also check this article:

[Change language of UI using custom control in SharePoint 2010](http://www.n8d.at/blog/sharepoint-2010/change-language-of-ui-using-custom-control/)