# Cannot Change Language in SP 2016

Tags: 2013, 2016, site-collection, language, alternate-language

The environment I have consists of two site collections.
One site collection is the User's MySite, and another site collection is a general site and subsites used and shared by all users.

I've installed an Arabic language pack on both site collections, and when I change the region settings in the MySite, it changes the language as intended. But when I change the language on the other site collection, no changes appear.

I want to change the language in the SharePoint menus, site settings, site contents etc. In the Site Settings, under Language Settings, the "Alternate Language" is checked, and also the "Overwrite Translations" is selected as "Yes".

I've tried the following solutions, but nothing seems to work:
1. http://thebitsthatbyte.com/switch-sharepoint-2013-page-language-to-user-preferred-language-using-javascriptjquery/
2. http://sharepointgauravgoyal.blogspot.com/2017/02/change-language-for-current-user-with.html
3. [Change Sharepoint language with a link?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27404/change-sharepoint-language-with-a-link)
4. https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=togglelanguage

So far, I'm able to get the language id being changed in the page's cookie, but the page lanugage still doesn't change.
I'm ready to go to any lengths to get it working, so any kind of help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the user's preferred language to Arabic via their user profile settings? Site Language settings will pick up on this (though the setting can take a while to take effect).

Comment: Yes, that option is only on the MySite site collection, which has the user profile. The other site collection does not have a user profile, and this is where I want to change the language.

Comment: So the other site collections will pick up a display language for the user from their language setting in their user profile. Note that they do not access Site Settings in their user profile, they literally edit their profile properties and choose a display language: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/change-your-personal-language-and-region-settings-caa1fccc-bcdb-42f3-9e5b-45957647ffd7

Comment: Yes, I've done the steps provided in the link. Thing is, when I change the language in the user profile, the user pages language change. But when I navigate to the other site collection from a link on this user's page, no changes show.
So is there a way to pass on the language to the other site collection?

Comment: It should pick it up automatically. However, I have seen in the past (especially with SharePoint Online) that it can take up to an hour for the other site collections to start appearing in the other language. If you are on prem (which I think you may be) and you are non-production, you can try an app pool recycle on the non-User Profile web app to see if there is some cache hanging around.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of things might be wrong, as I'm a bit new to sharepoint, but after applying this solution (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=togglelanguage) I'm manually changing the language id on the site by clicking a button. So shouldn't this result in the site collection language changing the same way?

Comment: The User Profile change you're talking about is already done. And it take a minute for the language to appear on the user's personal site only. Which is alright. But how can I take this change to my other site collection?

Comment: Are you able to try an app pool recycle? My guess at the moment is a caching issue.

Comment: Alright, I'm not on prem right now. I'll give it a shot when I'm able to get back to it. Really appreciate your support!

Comment: I've tried an app pool recycle on all my apps, and have it given it an hour. Also opened the browser in incognito to ensure no caching occurs, but unfortunately the language doesn't change :(